# Enum pegando próximo código em Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

Tenho uma classe no java que um de seus atributos é um enum e tem os seguintes valores:

```
    HIPERTROFIA(1, "Hipertrofia"),
    DEFINICAO(2, "Definição"),
    RESISTENCIA(3, "Resistência"),
    OUTROS(4, "Outros");
```

Quando eu envio o valor 0, salva no banco o valor 1. Quando eu envio o valor 1, salva no banco o valor 2 e por aí vai.

```
package br.com.academia.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import br.com.academia.domain.enums.StatusSerie;
import br.com.academia.domain.enums.TipoSerie;

@Entity
public class Solicitacao implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
"seqSolicitacao")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqSolicitacao", sequenceName = 
"seq_id_solicitacao")
private Integer id;

private Integer tipoSerie;
//definição de todos os atributos

public Solicitacao() {
    super();
}


public Solicitacao((...), TipoSerie tipoSerie, (...)) {
    super();
    (...)
    this.tipoSerie = (tipoSerie == null) ? null : tipoSerie.getCodigo();
    (...)

}


//get e set

public TipoSerie getTipoSerie() {
    return TipoSerie.toEnum(tipoSerie);
}


public void setTipoSerie(TipoSerie tipoSerie) {
    this.tipoSerie = tipoSerie.getCodigo();
}

//get e set

}
```

A classe enum:

```
package br.com.academia.domain.enums;

public enum TipoSerie {

HIPERTROFIA(1, "Hipertrofia"),
DEFINICAO(2, "Definição"),
RESISTENCIA(3, "Resistência"),
OUTROS(4, "Outros");

private int codigo;
private String descricao;

private TipoSerie(int codigo, String descricao) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public static TipoSerie toEnum(Integer codigo)
{
    if(codigo == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    for (TipoSerie serie: TipoSerie.values())
    {
        if(codigo.equals(serie.getCodigo()))
        {
            return serie;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Código inválido" + codigo);
}


}
```

Imagens que demonstram o problema:

[image: imagem 1]

[image: imagem 2]

Reparem que no postman eu envio 0 e no banco salvou 1.

Meu resource, onde recebo a requisição

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Solicitacao> create(@Valid @RequestBody Solicitacao solicitacao)
    {
    solicitacao = solicitacaoService.save(solicitacao);

    URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
            .path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(solicitacao.getId()).toUri();
    return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
    }
```

No service eu só faço alguns sets em alguns valores, mas não faço nenhuma alteração no tipoSerie, que por sua vez, já chega no service com valor errado.

Comment: Você disse que "Quando eu envio o valor 0, salva no banco o valor 1. Quando eu envio o valor 1, salva no banco o valor 2 e por ai vai. " Não seria o contrário (envia valor 1, salva o valor 0)? Já que não existe nenhuma enum com o valor 0 no seu exemplo. Além disso, seus atributos/getters não estão anotados?

Comment: É isso mesmo amigo, quando eu envio o 0 ele salva o 1. Reparei isso após tentar salvar o 1 e ele salvar insistentemente o valor 2. O que não entendo é que defini o código a ser atribuído pra cada valor. O atributo tipoSerie está sem anotação sim, só tem anotação nos outros atributos que não citei no post.

Comment: Porque você está enviando o valor 0 se o menor código da sua *enum* é 1? Ele não deveria lançar uma exceção nesse caso com a mensagem "Código inválido"?

Comment: Brother, eu tbm qria entender isso. Era pra estourar a exceção! É como se o java ignorasse o código que defini e assumisse a contagem a partir do zero. Eu sei q isso acontece quando não se define o código, por exemplo HIPERTROFIA("Hipertrofia") se eu coloco assim, o hipertrofia seria zero. Dá uma olhada nessas imagens.

Comment: Acredito que o problema ocorre quando você converte o JSON para o seu objeto. Talvez ele esteja utilizando o *ordinal* ao invés do método `toEnum` para criar o `TipoDeSerie` e injetá-lo no *setter*. Você editar sua pergunta e colocar o código onde você recebe a requisição?

Comment: já adicionei lá, Felipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando o Jackson vai desserializar um JSON e as propriedades `AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS` e `AUTO_DETECT_SETTERS` estão com o valor `true` (valor padrão), os *setters/getters* do seu objeto são utilizados para populá-lo (caso existam).

Como o seu *setter* recebe uma *enum* do tipo `TipoSerie`, o Jackson tenta utilizar o número informado no seu JSON para identificar qual o é elemento correspondente na *enum*. O problema é que o Jackson não sabe que deve utilizar o método `toEnum` já que você não o informou. Então ele utiliza a forma padrão nessa conversão, que é através do *ordinal* (quando o valor é um número). Por isso, quando você informa o valor 0, ele retorna o elemento `HIPERTROFIA` (índice 0, código 1).

Para que ele passe a utilizar o método `toEnum` para desserializar o JSON, você deve anotar tal método com `@JsonCreator`, assim ele fará a conversão da forma esperada.

Da mesma forma que você precisa informá-lo sobre como desserializar o JSON, você precisa informá-lo sobre como serializar o objeto. Para isso, você deve utilizar a anotação `@JsonValue` no seu método `getCodigo`.

Sendo assim, sua enum `TipoSerie` ficaria dessa forma:

```
public enum TipoSerie {

    HIPERTROFIA(1, "Hipertrofia"),
    DEFINICAO(2, "Definição"),
    RESISTENCIA(3, "Resistência"),
    OUTROS(4, "Outros");

    private int codigo;
    private String descricao;

    private TipoSerie(int codigo, String descricao) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static TipoSerie toEnum(Integer codigo) {
        if(codigo == null) {
            return null;
        }

        for (TipoSerie serie: TipoSerie.values()) {
            if(codigo.equals(serie.getCodigo())) {
                return serie;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Código inválido" + codigo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mestre, simplesmente fantástico! Muito boa a explicação. Essas 2 anotações resolveram esse problema. Muito obrigado, Felipe :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar usar um [`Converter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Converter.html)/[`AttributeConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html):

```
package br.com.academia.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import br.com.academia.domain.enums.StatusSerie;
import br.com.academia.domain.enums.TipoSerie;

@Entity
public class Solicitacao implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqSolicitacao")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqSolicitacao", sequenceName = "seq_id_solicitacao")
    private Integer id;

    private TipoSerie tipoSerie;

    // Definição de outros atributos.

    public Solicitacao() {
        super();
    }

    public Solicitacao(/*...,*/ TipoSerie tipoSerie /*, ...*/) {
        super();
        // ...
        this.tipoSerie = tipoSerie;
        // ...
    }

    // Getters e setters.

    public TipoSerie getTipoSerie() {
        return tipoSerie;
    }

    public void setTipoSerie(TipoSerie tipoSerie) {
        this.tipoSerie = tipoSerie;
    }
}
```

```
public enum TipoSerie {
    HIPERTROFIA("Hipertrofia"),
    DEFINICAO("Definição"),
    RESISTENCIA("Resistência"),
    OUTROS("Outros");

    private final String descricao;

    private TipoSerie(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return ordinal() + 1;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public static TipoSerie toEnum(Integer codigo) {
        if (codigo == null) return null;
        try {
            return values()[codigo - 1];
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Código inválido" + codigo, e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class MapeadorTipoSerie implements AttributeConverter<TipoSerie, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(TipoSerie x) {
        return x.getCodigo();
    }

    @Override
    public TipoSerie convertToEntityAttribute(Integer y) {
        return TipoSerie.toEnum(y);
    }
}
```

Observe também que você pode se aproveitar do [método `ordinal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()) que todo `enum` tem para derivar o código.

Comment: Mestre, mas nesse exemplo que você deu eu perco o controle do identificador do enum. Digamos q chegue um outro programador desatento e adicione um valor acima do HIPERTROFIA("Hipertrofia"), esse novo valor não iria assumir o valor de hipertrofia?

Comment: @MarceloNascimento Nesse caso, aí sim você precisaria do `getCodigo()` do jeito que era.